# How to measure WebRTC latency from python publisher to javscript subscriber?

Tags: video, webrtc, video-streaming, latency, aiortc

There is a problem with my webRTC program.
I used Python for publisher and JavaScript for subscriber when I used WebRTC, and then I want to get the e2e latency of the video.
And I'm also using a media server between a pub and a sub.

How can I get WebRTC e2e latency in this case?

I actually tried to use getStats() for this, but most of the examples were from javascript pub to javascript sub, so it didn't work well.

When using getStats()

```
Jitter buffer delay + decode delay + processing delay + InterFrame delay
```

I know this formula is not exactly for latency, but at this time I think I did my best.
If you have any ideas or formulas for waiting time, please help.